# Merging associative array with same values?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array -

```
{
"1":{"list_price_9":"1250.0000","list_price_18":"1250.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"1250.0000"},
"2":{"list_price_9":"0.0000","list_price_18":"0.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"1250.0000"},
"3":{"list_price_9":"0.0000","list_price_18":"0.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"1250.0000"},
"4":{"list_price_9":"0.0000","list_price_18":"0.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"1250.0000"},
"5":{"list_price_9":"0.0000","list_price_18":"0.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"1250.0000"},
"6":{"list_price_9":"2500.0000","list_price_18":"2500.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"2500.0000"},
"7":{"list_price_9":"0.0000","list_price_18":"0.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"2500.0000"}
}
```

I want to convert the array such that the resulting array has merged the keys with similar values in a comma separated string.

So the result will be something like this -

```
{
"1":{"list_price_9":"1250.0000","list_price_18":"1250.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"1250.0000"},
"2,3,4,5,7":{"list_price_9":"0.0000","list_price_18":"0.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"1250.0000"},
"6":{"list_price_9":"2500.0000","list_price_18":"2500.0000","golflan_price_9":"0.0000","golflan_price_18":"2500.0000"}
}
```

This seems simple, but I am not being able to come up with an elegant solution for this.
Kindly help.

I tried something like this -

```
  $common_prices = array();
  foreach ($pricelist as $day => $prices) {
    foreach ($common_prices as $new_day => $new_prices) {
      if($prices === $new_prices) {
        $modified_day = $new_day.','.$day;
        $common_prices[$modified_day] = $new_prices;
        unset($new_day);
      }
    }
    $common_prices[$day] = $prices;
  }
```

where $pricelist is the given array and $common_prices is the expected array. But obviously this will not work.

Comment: can you able to share the code as well what you have tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with linear complexity using intermediate array of accumulated keys for unique values:

```
$keys = [];

foreach($pricelist as $key=>$val) {
  $str = json_encode($val);
  if(!isset($keys[$str])) {
    $keys[$str] = [];
  }
  $keys[$str][] = $key;
}

$common_prices = [];
foreach($keys as $key=>$val) {
  $common_prices[join(',',$val)] = json_decode($key);
}
```

Comment: You can solve this task without a few `foreach` loops and multiple data conversions to JSON and back to array.

Comment: @Neodan, please check https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/32e8e16304250baa55bcdf62b41a4048250863a8/ext/standard/array.c#L1564 `array_search` does loop through the array and does convert data to a hash. Although it might be quicker than conversion to json, doing it within the foreach loop gives you O(n^2) complexity vs O(n*2) with 2 consecutive loops.

Comment: can you try this gist.github.com/Ocramius/1290076 ? For me array_search is faster.

Comment: The gist compares `array_search` vs `foreach`. In our case it is `foreach(){array_search();};` vs `foreach();foreach();`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 2):

You can just aggregate keys and data in the separated arrays and then combine them.

Example:

```
$keys = [];
$data = [];

foreach ($pricelist as $day => $prices) {
    if ($key = array_search($prices, $data))
        $keys[$key] .= ',' . $day;
    else {
        $keys[] = $day;
        $data[] = $prices;
    }
}

$common_prices = array_combine($keys, $data);
```